# Problem with GeoCoordinateWatcher - GeoPositionPermission denied for one application, but granted for another one

Tags: c#, gps

I have a strange problem here. I'm running Windows 10 on a Dell Latitude 7220 tablet and I have written an WPF application that among other functions uses the GeoCoordinateWatcher for displaying the GPS coordinates.
I do not get the permission (GeoPositionPermission is Denied) and the status (GeoPositionStatus is disabled) to do so.

I checked that the position service is activated in Windows.

So I wrote another small WPF application that only has the function to get the data from the GeoCoordinateWatcher and displays it. Strangely this works, GeoPositionPermission is Granted and GeoPositionStatus is Ready.

Both applications are WPF applications, not UWP. So how can it be that one application has access and the other one not? I can even run both of them and one will show the data and the other one can't.

Comment: Were both applications compiled on same machine?  Do both application target same version of Net.  Are there any differences in compiler options like X86, X64?  You can use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler in the same subnet and capture the working and non work requests and check for differences.

Comment: Can you check in the windows settings, more specifically, in the Privacy, and then in the Location section, if your application was not denied access to the data for whatever reasons ?

Comment: .NET version is the same (4.7.2) and both applications are compiled on the same machine as X64 versions. Maybe wireshark can help. The windows settings for accessing location service per app only apply to UWP apps as I understand.

Comment: As it turned out, there was not a problem with the position permissions at all. I had created an additional GeoCoordinateWatcherFake class for some cases when I don't have gps sensors available and this one was active instead of the real GeoCoordinateWatcher. My mistake.